# Powerbuilder OrcaScript: How to get latest for a subset of PBLs

Tags: build-automation, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

**OrcaScript is Handy**

I've used PowerBuilder OrcaScript before to automate a build PC's connecting to source control, getting the latest copy of the application objects, and then building the application. But that was on a project where the entire application was at our disposal and we owned all the code, and OrcaScript had no problem building the entire app.

**But now I only need to get latest on a subset of PBLs**

I'm now working on a project where we are customizing an existing third-party application. So I need to be able to reference all the proprietary third-party PBDs but only refresh the PBLs from source that contain our custom code that integrates into the vendor app's framework. We will only move the updated custom PBLs to the application directory when the refresh is complete.

I've been experimenting quite a bit but haven't been able to successfully refresh only the subset of PBLs that I want.

First, is this possible to do in OrcaScript?

Second, if it is possible, what am I missing? I have successfully:

- set the properties and connected to source control
- performed a "get latest" on the target, which seems to cause OrcaScript to create the needed empty PBLs
- excluded the proprietary third-party PBDs from the lib list

The problem is on the `scc refresh target` command. Logs show the process failing due to a write access issue, but the problem object or library is not specified. I have tried removing the read-only status from the objects in the list but this doesn't seem to be the issue.

I've experimented with various refresh type and build options but can't seem to get past the refresh.

--- ADDENDUM ---

**Orcascript:**

```
start session

scc get connect properties "Y:\Project\Release\PBWorkspace.pbw"
scc connect
scc set target "Y:\Project\Release\Starboard.pbt" "outofdate exclude_checkout"

scc get latest version "Y:\Project\Release\Starboard.pbt"
scc exclude liblist “Many proprietary PBDs excluded here”

scc refresh target "migrate"
scc close

;File copies to happen here

end session
```

---

Running orcascr9.exe ultimately yields this error at the refresh:
Orca error in ‘scc refresh target’. Result Code -22.

The log is below.

```
6/16/2011   17:15 Source Management Initialization...
        Scc Provider: PushOk SVNSCC
Connection to source control established

PBORCA_SccSetTarget: y:\project\release\Starboard.pbt

Target settings: REFRESH OUT OF DATE | EXCLUDE CHECKOUT 

PushOk SVNSCC Status: Fetching file list for: Y:/Project/Release/
  App Name: Starboard    App Lib: y:\Files\StarboardPB\application.pbl
  Library List: Many PBLs and PBDs identified

Successfully created library: c:\projects\Starboard scripts\powerbuilderobjects\custom.pbl
Successfully created library: c:\projects\Starboard scripts\powerbuilderobjects\custom_maps.pbl

PBORCA_SccGetLatestVer
PBORCA_SccExcludeLibraryList:
        Much excluding going on here

PBORCA_SccRefreshTarget. Migrate and Full Rebuild
PushOk SVNSCC Status: Fetching file list for: C:/Projects/Starboard Scripts/PowerBuilderObjects

PushOk SVNSCC Status: Fetching status for : C:/Projects/Starboard Scripts/PowerBuilderObjects
```

**If I delete the PBLs out of the directory, I get the following errors upon refresh**

```
DIFF2002 SccDiff error.  Unable to read PBL source for  c:\projects\Starboard scripts\powerbuilderobjects\custom.pbl(d_nautical.srd)

Calling cm_rebuild_application(CM_REBUILD_MIGRATE).
(0002): Error   C0193: One or more of the files in your library list could not be opened for write.

Errors encountered during import/compile.  Check SMS log.
PBORCA_SccClose
6/16/2011   17:16 Source control terminated
```

**If I leave the PBLs in place, I get this**

```
Calling cm_rebuild_application(CM_REBUILD_MIGRATE).
(0001): Error       C0193: One or more of the files in your library list could not be opened for write.
```

Comment: Can you post your orcascript and the relevant part of the log? If there's anything sensitive just do a global replace with foo, bar, etc. Also post the command you're using to run it if it's any more than orcascrxxx.exe myorcascript.orca >mylog.log.

Comment: Also, are you logging the orcascript itself? `set build_log = "mybuildlog.scc.log"` `scc set connect property logfile build_log`.

Comment: @Hugh Brackett I added excerpts from the scripts. Thanks for your input.

Comment: **1.** When you say you leave the PBLs in place, do you mean fully-populated, e.g. copied from development machine, or just from previous failed run?  **2.** After you run Orcascript, do all of the objects in your PBLs have the compile date of the Orcascript run?

Comment: @Hugh Brackett 1. Yes, in that case I mean leaving them there; though most guides I've read say to delete them first. 2. The problem is that the process bombs out before all the objects get populated. I'll try again and see if any objects at all are getting in there and what date they have.

Comment: This might be it: [PB9 had a bug that made builds fail if PBDs are read-only](http://search.sybase.com/kbx/changerequests?bug_id=381466)

Comment: Do you have any Proxies, objects that inherit from Throwable, or objects that throw the aforementioned objects? We gave up trying to get Orcascript to build these and we put them in PBDs that are built on a developer machine. One of those last two might be OK but we were tired of experimenting on our build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Hugh Brackett, for trying to help me out. I was unable to get past the read errors when using native OrcaScript. So unfortunately I don't have an actual answer for the question as written, except to say that in my experience, that "No, PB 9 does not support refreshing from source control a subset of PBLs when PBDs are part of the library list."

I do have a work around, albeit one that is not cheap. I have heard nothing but good things about PowerGen, a third-party tool for PowerBuilder builds and deployment. I tried out the trial app, and I must say it is outstanding. It seems to be able to do anything you need.

I tested a build automation script. PowerGen notified me it couldn't open the PBD files but continued to refresh the custom PBL objects I wanted loaded. The problem is solved, though it cost some cash to do it.

Comment: I've been using PowerGen since PB v6.  It's not as cheap as rolling your own OrcaScript, but I haven't yet found something I needed to do in automated PB builds that I can't get done.

Comment: Definitely another vote for PowerGen.  We use it to do hourly builds of two separate applications.